# Move/Drag Markers With JVectorMap

Tags: javascript, jvectormap

I'm working on a war-like game where players can control a country and move their armies across a map. I have decided to use JVectorMap to create the maps. I am looking for a way to drag markers across the map within a certain range.

Say my marker is located at 0,0. I should be able to drag my marker within X radius of that location and no further. I'll be using PHP for most of the backend and will have the moves 'confirmed' or whatever when a player hits the submit button.